# Load only information that we have already in qlikview

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

How can we load just the information that we already have in qlikview:

```
PERSON:
LOAD NUMBER,
     NAME,
     AGE
FROM TABLE_1;
```

In this list load only number where exist already in table_1

```
LIST:
LOAD 
     NUMBER   
FROM TABLE_2;
```

Your help is appreciated,

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the [keep](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/3.1/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/Keep.htm) function.

```
left keep (TABLE_1)

LIST:
LOAD 
     NUMBER   
FROM TABLE_2;
```

`left keep` will filter the records in `LIST` table and will leave only the `NUMBER` values which exists in `TABLE_1` and will keep both tables separated

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, consider using the EXISTS statment in a preeceding load :

```
LIST:
LOAD *
WHERE EXISTS(NUMBER);
LOAD 
    NUMBER   
FROM TABLE_2;
```